# Are "error" and "problem" meta-tags?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

From http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/:

1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.

   Clearly, [error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error) and [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem) fit this criterion.
2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

   [error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error) is more for error messages, so no, but...

   [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem) is more subjective. What may be a problem to some people is a benefit to another.

There are currently 170+ questions tagged [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem)

Comment: [`problem`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem) gets my vote. But [`error`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error) I'm not so sure about - maybe it would be better renamed as `error-message`?

Comment: I would still argue that `error-message` is not a useful tag.  It in no way describes or categorizes the question.

Comment: `problem` gets my vote too, perhaps we could go through the `error` tag to get a better view.

Comment: This seems related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77059/tag-ban-request-problem-and-problems...

Comment: I also asked this question on MSO some time ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60816/what-to-do-with-generic-ambigious-and-not-very-helpful-tags

Comment: Why there is no explanation of the tag when you mouse over it?

Answer (score 4):

IMO both are meta tags. [error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error) could mean error messages or an error that happened during photo copy/ other operation. Problem.. hmm yeah but what's the problem ?

Comment: that > what? (15)

Comment: @hello >__> I keep making stupid typos... and only you notice them :(