# Can [problem] be obliterated or merged to [troubleshooting]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Most of the questions are using [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem) as a meta tag, can that tag perhaps be obliterated?

**Update:** I looked through all tags, re-tagged only one to [troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) because it was necessary...

**Alternative suggestion:** Can [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem) me merged into [troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting)? It would make sense.

Comment: Duh http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1648/are-error-and-problem-meta-tags (Why is it that better arguments get less response?)

Comment: @Hello71: Was retagging similar questions with only a low number of questions till I suddenly saw that tag, I seem to have forgotten your question. Perhaps the [retag-request] might have made a difference. Anyhow, it's gone now... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now complete.

[image]

There are two [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions that need cleanup (and possible deletion if they are low quality).