# Please burninate the [problem] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, meta-tags

We've [had it before](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2034/can-problem-be-obliterated-or-merged-to-troubleshooting) and [way before that](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1648/are-error-and-problem-meta-tags), and [also on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77059/tag-ban-request-problem-and-problems), but the "problem" (which is [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem)) seems to be reappearing.

Can we please get rid of this meta-tag *again*?

By the way: There are a few [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions left to clean up.

Comment: [tag:untagged] questions retagged (as of 3/18/2012)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<waves hand>`

I see no [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem) here.

(but seriously should we blacklist this?)

Comment: I just cleared it, but please do proceed with blacklisting problem. It creates more... problems.

Comment: ok I did, but bear in mind if there are no matches in a 6 month period, the blacklist entry is cleared...

Comment: Please do so. Hey, we even say that we should have questions "based on actual **problems** that you face". So, that's the king of the meta tags, isn't it?

Comment: Okay, that works. Thanks @JeffAtwood